# Realm: Pushing RLMObjects to Parse as PFObject, mapping issue with RLMArray type (relationships)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, realm, pfobject

I am using https://github.com/newlix/PRSync/ to sync `RLMObjects` to Parse backend and vice versa. Let's say I need to push a `RLMObject`, I use the following function from the `PRSync.swift`.

```
public func pushObjectEventually<T:RLMObject where T:Syncable>(obj:T) {
  let pfo = PFObject(className: Constants.SaveActionClassName)
  pfo["parseClassName"] = T.className()
  for prop in properties(T.self) {
    if prop != "objectId" {
      pfo[prop] = obj[prop]
    }
  }
  pfo["timestamp"] = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
  pfo.saveEventually { success, error in
    if error != nil {
      println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
```

If I have a `RLMObject` that does not hold a to-many relationship with another object (i.e. does not contain and `RLMArray` type) everything works well. However, for `RLMObjects` that have `RLMArray` types (e.g. Client has to-many relationship with Entry), the function crashes-

```
 'PFObject values may not have class: RLMArray'
```

Could someone from Realm advise me on the best approach for mapping my `RLMArray` entries containing `Entry` objects (having to-many relationship)  in the `Client` `RLMObject`, when I want to convert the `Client` object to a `PFObject` and save it to Parse backend? I am sorry, but I did not find a lot of literature explaining this properly.

```
 class Client: RLMObject, Syncable {

    dynamic var objectId:String = ""
    dynamic var identifier:String = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var timestamp:Double = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    dynamic var address = Address()
    dynamic var notes: String = ""
    dynamic var phone: String = ""
    dynamic var fax: String = ""
    dynamic var email: String = ""
    dynamic var website: String = ""
    dynamic var entries = RLMArray (objectClassName: Entry.className())

    override class func primaryKey() -> String! {
        return "identifier"
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like Parse wants that RLMArray to be an NSArray instead of an RLMArray... have you tried transforming the array and setting that as the property on the PFObject?

Comment: I spoke with newlix separately and got to know that he does not intend prsync to handle relations in RLMObject, instead he advised me to use a non-relational approach. He also mentioned (too bad)  that he is not going to maintain the library anymore "because it's too hard to test against a Parse backend efficiently and is lack of automatically backup tools."